# How do I specify the use of repeated labels in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below I have an example of a simple horizontal bar chart made in Python 3 with Matplotlib:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

labels = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Mouse']
amounts = [5, 10, 12, 30]

plt.barh(labels, amounts)
plt.show()
```

Which produces the following graph:

[image]

As you can see, the default behavior is that the first "Dog" label and value gets ignored. However, I would like for two separate "Dog" points to be graphed, one at 5 and one at 12. How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First plot by unique ticks and then rename

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

labels = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Mouse']
ticks = range(len(labels))
amounts = [5, 10, 12, 30]

fig = plt.barh(ticks, amounts)
plt.yticks(ticks, labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want a histogram, just mention the direction of text here. You can add space to make strings different (like ' Dogs'). Tested it with approx. 20 spaces added in front of text, they don't break formatting. This approach is easy to implement in a program, if you need: just add enough spaces before each repeating element.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

labels = ['Dog', 'Cat', '                       Dog', 'Mouse']
amounts = [5, 10, 12, 30]

plt.barh(labels, amounts)
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]